# Python PDF module and Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x, pdf

I'm teaching myself Python thanks to a book and nice people i find every day in SO. Thanks all of you.

The question is that i been using VS, because i find it easy, but idk how/where to write commands like "python pythonprogram.py" and make use of the optparse module as i do on a Linux console.

The program i'm working on extracts the metadata from a pdf and it's the code below.

```
import PyPDF2
import optparse

def printMeta(fileName):

pdfFile = pdfFileReader(file(fileName, 'rb'))
docInfo = pdfFile.getDocumentInfo()
print('[*] PDF Metadata For: ' + str(fileName))

for metaItem in docInfo:
    print('[+]' + metaItem + ':' + docInfo[metaItem])

def main():

parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage %prog' + '-F <PDF File Name>')
parser.add_option('-F', dest='fileName', type='string', help='specify PDF file Name')
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
fileName = options.fileName

if fileName == None:
    print(parser.usage)
    exit(0)
else:
    printMeta(fileName)

if __name__ == '__main__':     
fileName = 'pdftest.pdf'
main()
```

This is a double question, one about VS proper use and the other to ask if my code works. I want to say that the pdftest.pdf is in the python program folder so i don't need a direction if i'm right. Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python development in VS, but the terminal/console on Windows can be started by running `cmd`. Open the Start Menu and type in "cmd".

Comment: My doubt is that i don't know how to make input in the style of 'print (Usage: bhpnet.py -t target_host -p port') like this. Another example would be "Python pythonprog.py -opt1 -opt2" I know how to use the optparse module but idk how to make the input. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't quite understand what you're having trouble with. What do you mean with "how to make the input"? You don't know how to invoke your program? Can you run python.exe from a `cmd` window?

Comment: Note that the `optparse` module has been deprecated since Python 3.2. Consider using `argparse` instead.

Comment: Idk how to invoke a Python program through 'cmd'

Comment: The Python FAQ entry [How do I run a Python program under Windows?](https://docs.python.org/3.5/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows) should be able to help you with that. You will also want to pass arguments to your application while debugging: [How do I pass command line arguments to Python from VS in Debug mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302508/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-python-from-vs-in-debug-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure where your relative path starts, you might want to use `os.chdir`

```
from os import chdir
chdir("path/to/my/python/file")
```

then, you'll be able to import files in the same directory even if you're running the script from another folder.

Hope that helps